# Can't search for numbers in a letter only array for hangman

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a hangman game for a project. The website asks the person for a number to guess and then make the blanks for the word. The one problem I'm having, is that I can input a word with numbers at the end, which is something I don't want.

So, basically I can input "Something12" and that will work. I can't figure out how to make it search for numbers in the array I have it saved too. I'm not sure what I need to code in order look and remove or reprompt the user for a valid word.

```js
/* Global Variables */
var guessWord = [];
var guessWord1 = [];
var underScores = [];
var letters = "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz";

/* Function for the Guess word, gets the word and puts in the underscores */
function gWord()
{
 // Asks for the word and removes punctuation 
 guessWord = prompt("Please input the guess word below");
 guessWord1 = guessWord.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");   
 
 // If it is not a word, will re-prompt for an actual word
 while(guessWord1 == "" || guessWord1 == null || isNaN(guessWord1) == false) 
 {
  var guessWord2 = guessWord1.search(letters);
  alert(guessWord2);
  
  if(guessWord1 != letters)
   {
    alert("This is not a valid word, please try again");
    guessWord = prompt("Please input the guess word below");
    guessWord1 = guessWord.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,""); 
   } 
 }
 
  for(var i = 0; i < guessWord1.length; i++)
   {
    underScores.push("_");
   }  
  document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML = underScores;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="author" content="" />
<meta name="Keywords" content="" />

<style type="text/css">

body {
width: 1280px;
background-color: grey; }

#contain {
height: 500px;
width: 1000px;
background-color: lightblue; 
border: 5px blue groove;
margin: auto; }

#replace {
width: 900px;
height: 125px;
border: 5px blue groove;
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
top: 350px;
left: 200px; }

#image {
border: 5px blue groove;
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 200px;
height: 250px;
width: 250px; }

#incorrect {
border: 5px blue groove;
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 600px;
height: 125px;
width: 400px; }

#Wrong {
position: absolute;
left: 110px;
top: -12px;
}

#button {
border: 5px blue groove;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 700px;
height: 50px;
width: 200px; 
font-size: 20px; 
cursor: pointer; }

#bText {
position: absolute;
left: 37px;
top: -12px;
}

#button:active {
left: 702px;
top: 202px; }

</style>

<script type="text/JavaScript" src="main.js">
</script>

</head>
<body onload= "gWord();">
<div id="contain">

<div id="replace">

</div>

<div id="image">


</div>
<div id="incorrect">
<h2 id="Wrong"><u>Incorrect Letters</u></h2>
<span id="wList">Hi</span>
</div>

<div id="button">
<h4 id="bText">Enter a Letter</h4>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your existing *regex* is working, adding `\d` to it will remove numbers as well.

```
guessWord1 = guessWord.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()\d]/g,"");
```

---

Updated with a better approach to inform users rather than simply remove unwanted characters.

*I also added a check if `Cancel` were pressed, and if, exit the game. If you don't want that, simply remove the line `if (!guessWord) { return false; }`*

Stack snippet

```js
/* Global Variables */
var guessWord = [];
var guessWord1 = [];
var underScores = [];

/* Function for the Guess word, gets the word and puts in the underscores */
function gWord() {
  // Asks for the word and removes punctuation 
  guessWord = prompt("Please input the guess word below");

  // If it is not a word, will re-prompt for an actual word
  while ((!guessWord || guessWord.length < 1 || !/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(guessWord))) {
  
      // If cancel, exit game
      if (!guessWord) { return false; }
      
      alert("This is not a valid word, please try again");
      guessWord = prompt("Please input the guess word below");
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < guessWord.length; i++) {
    underScores.push("_");
  }
  document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML = underScores;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <meta name="Keywords" content="" />

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      width: 1280px;
      background-color: grey;
    }
    
    #contain {
      height: 500px;
      width: 1000px;
      background-color: lightblue;
      border: 5px blue groove;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    #replace {
      width: 900px;
      height: 125px;
      border: 5px blue groove;
      background-color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: 350px;
      left: 200px;
    }
    
    #image {
      border: 5px blue groove;
      background-color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50px;
      left: 200px;
      height: 250px;
      width: 250px;
    }
    
    #incorrect {
      border: 5px blue groove;
      background-color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50px;
      left: 600px;
      height: 125px;
      width: 400px;
    }
    
    #Wrong {
      position: absolute;
      left: 110px;
      top: -12px;
    }
    
    #button {
      border: 5px blue groove;
      border-radius: 15px;
      background-color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: 200px;
      left: 700px;
      height: 50px;
      width: 200px;
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #bText {
      position: absolute;
      left: 37px;
      top: -12px;
    }
    
    #button:active {
      left: 702px;
      top: 202px;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="main.js">
  </script>

</head>

<body onload="gWord();">
  <div id="contain">

    <div id="replace">

    </div>

    <div id="image">


    </div>
    <div id="incorrect">
      <h2 id="Wrong"><u>Incorrect Letters</u></h2>
      <span id="wList">Hi</span>
    </div>

    <div id="button">
      <h4 id="bText">Enter a Letter</h4>
    </div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```